# Prove that U(n) is an embedded submanifold.

Tags: matrices, smooth-manifolds, submanifold, unitary-matrices

I am having trouble proving that U(n) is a submanifold of $M_n(\Bbb{C})$.
I thought about using the regular value theorem. I used the function $F:GL_n(\Bbb{C})\to M_n(\Bbb{C})$ by sending a matrix $A$ to $AA^*-I$ where $A^*$ is the adjugate of $A$. Then I saw for sure that $F^{-1}(Z) = U(n) = \{A\in GL_n(\Bbb C) : AA^*=I\} $ (Z is the zero matrix.)
So the next step I did was trying to show that $(dF)_A$ is surjective $\forall A\in U(n)$.
$(dF_A)(X) = \lim_{t \to 0} {F(A+tX)-F(A) \over t}$=$\lim_{t \to 0 }\frac{(A+tX)(A+tX)^* - I - AA^* +I}{t}=*$, since $A\in U(n)$ we get that $AA^*=I$ so we get the following: $*=\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{F(A+tX)}{t}$.
From here I don't know how to continue computing the derivative.
I am wondering if I could prove the same with another function $F$, or how to compute the derivative further. I think I can prove surjectivity myself if I have the derivative.

Comment: You can expand $$(A+tX)(A+tX)^*-AA^*=t(AX+XA)+t^2X^2.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the derivative you have
$$
F(A+tX) -F(A) = (A+tX)(A+tX)^*-AA^* = t(XA^*+AX^*)+t^2XX^*
$$
so that
$$
dF_A(X) = XA^*+AX^*.
$$

However note that $F:GL_n(\mathbb C)\to Mat_n(\mathbb C)$ is not a submersion (i.e. the differential is not everywhere surjective). Note also that if that were the case, the preimage $U_n$ would be zero-dimensional...

A wiser choice of range for the map $F$ yields the proof that you are after. What special properties does the matrix $AA^*$ have?

Comment: To find a solution of $XA^* + AX^* = H$, it suffices to solve $XA^* = (1/2)H$, which gives $X = (1/2)HA$. Indeed, if $X = (1/2)HA$, then $XA^* = (1/2)H$ and $AX^* = (1/2)H$.

Comment: I don’t really see how F maps into all Hermitian matrices… I see that F takes any matrix in $GL_n$ Into $AA^*-I=det(A)I-I=I(det(A)-1)$ this is the set is not all Hermitian matrices right?

Comment: @Main, yes oops, I meant that $dF_A: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to H_n$, where $H_n$ is the space of $n$ by $n$ hermitian matrices. I will erase that previous comment.

Comment: @Main, you have to be careful! The '*' here is the complex conjugate transpose, which is sometimes called the adjoint, but it is not to be confused with the transpose of the cofactor matrix, which is also sometimes called the adjoint or adjugate.

Comment: I see now thanks!